# How to preview image without saving it to file system?(JSF 2.0)

Tags: java, image, jsf, file-upload, java-ee-6

My web app has a JSF2.0 page that looks more or less like this:

[image]

I need to preview the image, before i upload it and save it to the file system:

Do you know is there any library that can help me do that easily? 
I use primefaces fileupload gadget currently, but i don't know how to just preview and then upload.

Could you give me some best practice tips on from where to start, in order to achieve my goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is very complex...theoretically is possible but complex..
when upload the file you should save the stream (byte[]) in the session of the user and after that make the img src url for a servlet that responds with the bytes saved earlier...
this is the theory...I don't know if there is something implemented...

Comment: You are right and I do not think it is SO complex. Obviously if you have uploaded file you do not have to save it to disk to show in browser. The problem is that he does not want to upload the file at all, i.e. he wants to be able to preview the file before  upload.

Comment: @AlexR Yes that is correct, i don't want to upload it. Also one more doubt is if the read and write permisions on the users computer, could also difficult this task even more. I never did that before, sounds really complicated.

Comment: is not so complicated made the servlet the only thing you need is to retrive the request stream as byte[] when is called in POST and save the byte[] in the session like _session.setAttribute("app.image.preview", bytes)_ and in the GET method send that attribute as response like: _response.getOutputStream().write((byte[])session.getAttribute("app.image.preview"))_ ...the hardest part is if you want that the preview is immediately after the user had choosen the image..because you need to simulating an ajax request to upload the img...

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry to disappoint you but I do not think it is possible at all with HTML. Browser allows you to upload files but you cannot get their content or file system path. So, the solution is to upload file first and then show its preview using AJAX.

Probably Flash or Flex give you this functionality, so, I'd recommend you to check these tools. And obviously you can use Java applet but it will limit your user base.